# Thread with "While True" loop injected through spring stops after three or four days of execution

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, scope, webserver

I'm developing a web site which is responsible for providing informations about an online radio. The webserver itself get informations from different sources (There is a database fed by an API, and also my streaming servers provide a few XML files that I use to extract several important informations on the fly).

Well, my problem started when I decided to create audience alarms based on a watchdog thread, that reads the XML files from streaming servers, update an array with a fix length (a long array of 360 places, pre allocated, so nothing that big) and is accessed by an Action, which returns this array to be transformed in a graph by a java script routine. This watchdog thread, so, needs to be the same to every client accessing the web site, since the informations it provides need to be equal to everyone. Thus, I decided to use the spring framework to call the service that starts the Watchdog thread.

It worked, every website sees the same information and the information was always updated... until the while true thread I created stopped, the last state of the array was kept, but the thread doesn't work anymore.

The spring injection is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ehcache="http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache"
    default-autowire="byName"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache http://www.springmodules.org/schema/cache/springmodules-ehcache.xsd">

    <bean id="wowzaService" class="br.com.imusica.reports.services.radio.WowzaService"/>

</beans>
```

The service (accessed through an action) is programmed as follows:

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class WowzaService extends AbstractService {

    @Autowired
    private WatchDogThread watchdog;

    public void startWatchdog() {
        watchdog.start();
    }

    public WatchDogArray getWatchdogArray() {
        return watchdog.getWatchDogArray();
    }
}
```

This service is injected at the ApplicationContextInitializer class, as follows:

```
public synchronized void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
    WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(contextEvent.getServletContext());

    WowzaService ws = (WowzaService) wac.getBean("wowzaService");
    ws.startWatchdog();

    CacheManager manager = (CacheManager) wac.getBean("cacheManager");
    MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ManagementService.registerMBeans(manager, mBeanServer, false, false, false, true);

    cleanUpService = (CleanUpService) wac.getBean("cleanUpService");
    ApplicationContextInitializer.applicationDiskRootPath = contextEvent.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

    ComplexReportsControllerService complexReportsService =
        (ComplexReportsControllerService) wac.getBean("complexReportsControllerService");
    complexReportsService.cleanUpUnfinishedReports();
    cleanUpService.setRootPath(ApplicationContextInitializer.applicationDiskRootPath);
    cleanUpService.cleanUpAllSessions();
    // StdScheduler schedulerFactoryBean;

    ApplicationContextInitializer.reportsBasePath = (String) wac.getBean("reportsDataPath");

}
```

The watchdog Thread is defined as a Component, and has a @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON) on it, extends thread, and so on. I'm wondering whether Spring is or not stopping this thread after some time. I assured that, when I update my data array, I don't append the information, but actually shift the values, discard the oldest one and insert the new value. So, a memory problem isn't happening.

Thanks in advance for your help

João Bruno

Comment: What's the exception handling in the `WatchDogThread.run` method?

Comment: Chances are your thread threw an exception.  You might want to consider wrapping your `run()` method in a `try { } catch (Throwable)` or using the `thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)`.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak I found 2 errors. Both had this line:

INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional imp
act.

Comment: I mean, there is nothing before describing an error related to my thread (And, actually, the log is huge, I tried to find the beginning of the error, but just found errors related to "This thread doesn't exist anymore"). Anyway, if I don't find the solution with spring, I'll make my thread static (It just occured to me!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring cannot stop your thread, your thread fails by some reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In fact, we found out that the problem was related to an untreated exception, which happens when we require information to a streaming server.